# Show UIAlertView or whatever dialog progress when UITableViewController on storyboard clicked iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview, uialertview, mbprogresshud

I have a storyboard with a navigation controller and a uiviewcontroller as my root, after this i have several uitableviewcontrollers connected by a push seague on cell click.

What i need, is to show an UIAlertView or some progress dialog (like MBProgressHUD) while the present controller is dismissed and the new one is showed.

I have tried set an UIAlertView on the click cell:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"I am dismissing"
                                       message:nil
                                      delegate:nil
                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

But the alert is showed until the next controller appears, how can i show the alert when the click is executed on the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i've found:

### Preparations:

1. Make your controller conform to protocol `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

   Example:
   `@interface YourViewController : UITableViewController`

   to
   `@interface YourViewController : UITableViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>`.
2. In storyboard, set the segue identifier. Let me call it *CellSegue* for this example.
   (To to so, click the segue in the storyboard, go to Attributes Inspector and there is Identifier field)
3. You will need 2 properties.
   `@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *selectedCellTableView;`
   `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath;`

### Coding:

The method below, displays `alertview` and prevents the cell from being selected by returning `nil`. We want to remember which cell was to become selected, so we set properties prepared before as follows:

```c
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"alert" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    _selectedCellTableView = tableView;
    _selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;

    [av show];

    return nil;
}
```

Lastly, in `UIAlertViewDelegate` method we handle a button click:

1. We get the cell at `_selectedCellIndexPath` from `_selectedCellTableView`,
2. We perform the *CellSegue* segue and set the cell as a sender.

```c
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    //1
    UITableViewCell *cell =[_selectedCellTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:_selectedCellIndexPath];

    //2
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CellSegue" sender:cell];

}
```

I hope it was what you were looking for :)